# Retrieving data from a database .. 

Tags: java, database

I wrote this code in order to store data in a database and see the result using *NetBeans* program. But there is no output and there is no compilation error. Can I know what is the problem? Is there any missing jar file

```java
package database;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.sql.*;

public class Database {

    static Connection conn;

    public Database() {
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        return conn;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not load the driver");
        }
        String user = "SYSTEM"; //readEntry("Enter userid:  ");
        String pass = "mevooo";//readEntry("Enter password: ");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE", user, pass);

        String query = "select Ref, Title,Risk_Rating, Root_cause, Impact, Likelihood, Efforts, Finding, Implication, Recommendation from  Lack_Of_Defense ";
        PreparedStatement myStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        myStatement.clearParameters();
        ResultSet myResult = myStatement.executeQuery(query);

        while (myResult.next()) {
            String Ref = myResult.getString(1);
            String Title = myResult.getString(2);
            String Risk_Rating = myResult.getString(3);
            String Root_cause = myResult.getString(4);
            String Impact = myResult.getString(5);
            String Likelihood = myResult.getString(6);
            String Efforts = myResult.getString(7);
            String Finding = myResult.getString(8);
            String Implication = myResult.getString(9);
            String Recommendation = myResult.getString(10);

            System.out.println(" =============================================================");
            System.out.println(" ===================== Lack of defense Table ==================");
            System.out.println(" Ref  : " + Ref);
            System.out.println(" Title " + Title);
            System.out.println(" Risk Rating " + Risk_Rating);
            System.out.println(" Root cause " + Root_cause);
            System.out.println(" Impact " + Impact);
            System.out.println(" Likelihood " + Likelihood);
            System.out.println(" Efforts " + Efforts);
            System.out.println(" Finding " + Finding);
            System.out.println(" Implication " + Implication);
            System.out.println(" Recommendation " + Recommendation);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no code. How are we expected to know what you've done and help you?

Comment: Please remove empty lines and commented out code. Make the program as small as possible without removing the error.

Comment: Try to debug step by step, you can resolve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem could be with below lines

```
        myStatement.clearParameters();
        ResultSet myResult = myStatement .executeQuery(query);
```

Is the clearParameters() really required? Also, remove the query parameter from the `executeQuery()` method. It is not required, as you are already setting it in the `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your result set is empty, have you tried to execute the query in a sql client app?

Comment: yes I wrote this statement in SQL command line and all my result are in on row ..!!